# Determining Column and Row

Tags: c++

This seems like such an easy thing to do, but I just can't figure it out... anyways, say I have a grid, let's say it's 100x100. Now let's say I have an element in position 34 of the grid, that being column 3 row 4. If I ONLY know the size of the grid (both x and y), how can I calculate the column and row it's currently in?

Visual example (5x5):

```
ooooo
ooooo
oowoo w is @ position 12, but how do I calculate this?
ooooo
ooooo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = position / width
c = position % width
```

Where r is the row the element is in, and c is the column the element is in, width is the width of the matrix

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your positions start at `(0,0)`

```
int x = pos%width;
int y = pos/width;
```

Comment: That only works if I already have the row and column. That gives me what I already have. Is there an inverse of that to find row and column from position?